# cant consume json data from kafka topic in scala

Tags: json, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, json-deserialization

I need to read json data from kafka topic. I am not able to consume json data from kafka topic.It will in infinite loop.

So far I suppose I need to:

Implement a custom serializer to convert JSON into byte array
implement a custom deserializer to convert byte array into JSON object
Produce the message
Read the message in Consumer class

```
package services

import java.util
import java.util.Properties

import constants.ConfigValues
import models.Device
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

class ConsumerService {


  def consumeDeviceData(topic: String) = {
    val props = new Properties()
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", ConfigValues.BOOTSTARP_SERVER)
    props.put("key.deserializer", ConfigValues.KEY_DESERIALIZER)
    //props.put("value.deserializer", ConfigValues.VALUE_DESERIALIZER)
    props.put("value.deserializer", classOf[CustomDeserializer] )
    props.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest")
    props.put("group.id", "device-consumer")
    val consumer = new KafkaConsumer[String, Device](props)
    println(consumer)
    consumer.subscribe(util.Arrays.asList(topic))
    while (true) {
      val record = consumer.poll(1000).asScala
      println("inside")
      println(record)
      for (device <- record.iterator)
        println(device.value())
       // GetDeviceResponse.fromDeviceObject(value.value())
    }
  }
}
```

CustomDeserializer class:

```
package services

import java.io.{ByteArrayInputStream, ObjectInputStream}
import java.util

import models.Device
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer

class CustomDeserializer extends Deserializer[Device] {

  override def configure(configs: util.Map[String, _], isKey: Boolean): Unit = {
  }

  override def deserialize(topic: String, bytes: Array[Byte]): Device = {

    val byteIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)
    val objIn = new ObjectInputStream(byteIn)
    val obj = objIn.readObject().asInstanceOf[Device]
    println(obj)
    byteIn.close()
    objIn.close()
    obj
  }

  override def close(): Unit = {

  }
}
```

Device class:

```
package models


class Device() {
  var DATE: Int=0
  var SOURCETYPE: String=""
  var DEVICEID: String=""
  var EVENTTIME: String=""
  var TIME: Int=0
  var COUNTRYCODE: String=""
  var COUNTRYNAME: String=""
  var COUNTY: String=""
  var DEVICELAT: String=""

  var DEVICELOGCREATEDAT: Double=0

  var DEVICELOGSTATUS: String=""

  var DEVICELONG: String=""

  var DEVICEHPE: String=""

  var DEVICERAWLOCID: String=""

  var DEVICERAWSTATE: String=""

  def this(DATE: Int ,SOURCETYPE: String,DEVICEID: String,EVENTTIME: String, TIME: Int, COUNTRYCODE: String,
  COUNTRYNAME: String, COUNTY: String, DEVICELAT: String, DEVICELOGCREATEDAT: Double, DEVICELOGSTATUS: String, DEVICELONG: String, DEVICEHPE: String, DEVICERAWLOCID: String, DEVICERAWSTATE: String)
{
  this()
  this.DATE=DATE
  this.COUNTRYCODE = COUNTRYCODE
  this.COUNTRYNAME =COUNTRYNAME
  this.DATE=DATE
  this.COUNTY=COUNTY
  this.DEVICEHPE=DEVICEHPE
  this.DEVICEID=DEVICEID
  this.DEVICELAT=DEVICELAT
  this.DEVICELOGCREATEDAT=DEVICELOGCREATEDAT
  this.DEVICELOGSTATUS=DEVICELOGSTATUS
  this.DEVICELONG=DEVICELONG
  this.DEVICERAWLOCID=DEVICERAWLOCID
  this.DEVICERAWSTATE=DEVICERAWSTATE
  this.EVENTTIME=EVENTTIME
  this.SOURCETYPE=SOURCETYPE
  this.TIME=TIME

}
}
```

Comment: Where is it blocking? Are you producing data while the consumer is running, since it's starting from the end of the topic?

Comment: I already produced data in one topic. After that I am reading data from that topic. When I am running this command bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic DeviceData --from-beginning --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --partition 0...then its shows d result

Comment: @OneCricketeer..When I am trying to deseralize the object then i am getting error ::com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('>' (code 62)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')

Comment: I don't know what serializer you're using, but `<` character isn't valid JSON... Plus, your shown code isn't using Jackson, so you need to edit your post to show what changed